# Best way to add/remove to an NSMutableArray managed by an NSArrayController

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary, nsarraycontroller

I've got a `NSMutableArray` (containing `NSMutableDictionary` instances) bound to an `NSArrayController` (the `NSArrayController` is in turn bound to `NSTableView` columns).

What is the most Cocoa-, and KVO- friendly way of, **programmatically** :

- adding a new empty object (`NSMutableDictionary`) to the array?
- removing currently selected object? (after removing, the previous item - if exists - should be selected)

*I've always been doing this in a way I don't particularly like - and I'm sure it's not the best way around (too many lines of code for something so simple : in Cocoa that indicates a wrong take on the subject :-)).*

---

**My code (quite an overkill, actually) :**

---

***Adding to the Array***

```
NSMutableArray* oldParams = [paramsArray mutableCopy];

[oldParams addObject:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Parameter",@"Parameter",@"",@"Value", nil]];
[self setParamsArray:oldParams];

[paramsController setSelectionIndex:[paramsArray count]-1];
```

***Removing currently selected object from the Array***

```
if ([paramsArray count]>0)
{
    int s = [paramsController selectionIndex];

    NSMutableArray* oldParams = [paramsArray mutableCopy];

    [oldParams removeObjectAtIndex:s];

    [self setParamsArray:oldParams];

    if (s<=[paramsArray count]-1)
        [paramsController setSelectionIndex:s];
    else
        [paramsController setSelectionIndex:[paramsArray count]-1];
}
```

So, what are your opinions on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to think of your array as the controller's backing store, and that it's managing it for you.

Adding an object:

```
[[self accountsArrayController] addObject:accountDictionary];
```

Removing the currently selected object:

```
[[self accountsArrayController] remove:nil];
```

You'll have to write another line or two to make that previous item selected, but that's an exercise I leave to you.

Comment: I'm getting a `Program received signal : "EXC_BAD_ACCESS"` in both cases... Any ideas?

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon : Possibly. Make sure that any previous use of the array controller doesn't include the use of `setContent:` (though I've found that using bindings to do that at the outset works just fine). And it goes without saying that your backing array should be a valid, allocated `NSMutableArray`.

Comment: My backing array IS perfectly valid. The thing is I can do ANY sort of processing directly to the array, but your approach (using the controller directly to handle the array) has never really worked for me...

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon : No insult intended; I only wanted to cover all the bases. I mentioned the `setContent:` because that's what had been causing `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` problems for me.

Comment: No insult at all; We're exchanging coding experience & know-how here... :-) (I'm posting my code to see what I mean)

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon : I would have said that your adding example wouldn't work because you're working behind the controller's back, but perhaps your call to setSelectionIndex: makes the controller 'aware' of that somehow. Same with your removing example. I would urge you to try the direct approach I initially described. I stumbled at first, but I'm glad I persevered.

Comment: Seemingly, I AM working behind my controller's back... but since the Array Controller is bound to the array... and the array is re-set in a KV-compliant manner (`[self setParamsArray:...]`), the controller IS aware of the changes... (Btw, I wish I could do it your way; only if it worked... My approach is admittedly ugly...)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9646/discussion-between-trudyscousin-and-dr-kameleon)

Answer (score 2):

Given that the array controller is bound to a property named paramsArray on some object, the best approach is to define the key-value coding [indexed accessors](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/AccessorConventions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002174-SW4) on that object's class.  Then, use those accessors to mutate the to-many relationship represented by the property in a KVO-compliant manner.

For example, implement -insertObject:inParamsArrayAtIndex: and then use that to add an object.  If you like the convenience of NSMutableArray's -addObject: method, you can write an -addObjectToParamArray method that forwards to -insertObject:inParamsArrayAtIndex:.

By the way, "paramsArray" is a poor name for a property.  The property name shouldn't encode the type used to implement it.  If you look at the templates for the indexed accessor names, you'll see that Apple is expecting to-many relationship properties to just be a plural noun like "params" (no "Array").  For example, -paramsAtIndexes: is better than -paramsArrayAtIndexes:.